# Navbar Partial Throwing ActionView::Template::Error Exception for notification gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, notifications

I'm using the **notification** gem by **rails-engine** https://github.com/rails-engine/notifications. It seems to be failing when I traverse to the controller index page for it. It's claiming that the links in my navigation partial are undefined when they clearly are. The NotificationController is the only one having this issue right now. I never used this gem before today. My code is below

Exception

```
Started GET "/notifications" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-09-04 16:06:51 -0400
Processing by Notifications::NotificationsController#index as HTML
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Notification Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY id desc LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 25], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Rendering notifications/notifications/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered notifications/notifications/index.html.erb within layouts/application (96.1ms)
  Rendered nav_partials/_user_navbar.html.erb (2572.3ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8155ms (ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `dashboard_index_path' for #<#<Class:0xc0ceb08>:0xc0ccff0>):
     6: 
     7:     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-md-0 user-nav-li-padding">
     8:       <li class="nav-item white-nav-link mobile-nav-link">
     9:         <%= active_link_to dashboard_index_path, class_active: 'nav-link active', :class_inactive => 'inactive' do %>
    10:             <div class="left">
    11:               <%= inline_svg 'user_navbar_icons/home_icon_inactive.svg', width: 50, height: 50 %>
    12:             </div>
```

_navbar.html.erb

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm pull-nav-to-front">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right hidden-md-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="toggle navigation" style="background-color: #fdfeff;">&#9776;</button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse mobile-nav-bg" id="navbar-collapse">

    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-md-0 user-nav-li-padding">
      <li class="nav-item white-nav-link mobile-nav-link">
        <%= active_link_to dashboard_index_path, class_active: 'nav-link active', :class_inactive => 'inactive' do %>
            <div class="left">
              <%= inline_svg 'user_navbar_icons/home_icon_inactive.svg', width: 50, height: 50 %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              <p>My Dashboard</p>
            </div>

        <% end %>

      </li>

      <li class="nav-item white-nav-link mobile-nav-link">
        <%= active_link_to posts_path, class_active: 'nav-link active', :class_inactive => 'inactive' do %>
            <div class="left">
              <%= inline_svg 'user_navbar_icons/post_icon_inactive.svg', width: 50, height: 50 %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              <p>Posts</p>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item white-nav-link mobile-nav-link">
        <%= active_link_to mailbox_index_path, class_active: 'nav-link active', :class_inactive => 'inactive' do %>
            <div class="left">
              <%= inline_svg 'user_navbar_icons/mail_icon_inactive.svg', width: 50, height: 50 %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              <p>Messages</p>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item white-nav-link mobile-nav-link">
          <small class="badge badge-default notifications-counter-badge"><%= notification_count_for(current_user) %></small>
        <%= active_link_to notifications_path, class_active: 'nav-link active', :class_inactive => 'inactive' do %>

            <div class="left">
              <%= inline_svg 'user_navbar_icons/notification_icon_inactive.svg', width: 50, height: 50 %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              <p>Notifications</p>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item white-nav-link mobile-nav-link">
        <%= active_link_to favorites_index_path, class_active: 'nav-link active', :class_inactive => 'inactive' do %>
            <div class="left">
              <%= inline_svg 'user_navbar_icons/favorite_icon_inactive.svg', width: 50, height: 50 %>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
              <p>Favorites</p>
            </div>
        <% end %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item white-nav-link mobile-nav-link">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <%= active_link_to '#', active: false, class: 'btn dropdown-toggle', class_active: 'nav-link active ', :class_inactive => 'inactive', id: 'dropdownmenubtn', data: { toggle: 'dropdown' }, aria: {haspopup: true, expanded: false } do %>
              <div class="left">
                <%= inline_svg 'user_navbar_icons/settings_icon_inactive.svg', width: 50, height: 50 %>
              </div>
              <div class="right">
                <p>Settings</p>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right settings-dropdown-menu-margin-pos dropdown-menu-font-color" aria-labelledby="dropdownmenubtn">
                <h6 class="dropdown-header"><%= current_user.username %></h6>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <%= link_to 'Account Settings', edit_user_registration_path, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
                <%= link_to 'Help', user_help_index_path, class: 'dropdown-item' %>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <%= link_to 'Logout', destroy_user_session_path, class: 'dropdown-item', method: :delete %>
              </div>
          <% end %>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
      $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
  });
</script>
```

application.html.erb

```
   <body>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= render 'nav_partials/user_navbar' %>
    <% elsif admin_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'nav_partials/admin_navbar' %>
    <% else %>
        <%= render 'nav_partials/navbar' %>
    <% end %>
<%= yield %>
    </body>
```

notifications_controller.rb

```
module Notifications
  class NotificationsController < Notifications::ApplicationController

    def index
      @notifications = notifications.includes(:actor).order('id desc').page(params[:page])

      unread_ids = @notifications.reject(&:read?).select(&:id)
      Notification.read!(unread_ids)

      @notification_groups = @notifications.group_by { |note| note.created_at.to_date }
    end

    def clean
      notifications.delete_all
      redirect_to notifications_path
    end

    private

    def notifications
      raise "You need reqiure user login for /notifications page." unless current_user
      Notification.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
  end
end
```

notifications index

```
<div class="notifications row">
  <div class="heading clearfix">
    <%= t('notifications.all_notifications') %>

    <span class="pull-xs-right">
      <%= link_to t('notifications.clean_all'), notifications.clean_notifications_path, class: 'btn btn-sm btn-secondary', method: 'delete' %>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="list">
    <% if @notifications.blank? %>
      <div class="no-records"><%= t('notifications.no_records') %></div>
    <% else %>
      <% @notification_groups.each do |group, notifications| %>
        <div class="notification-group">
          <div class="group-title"><%= group %></div>
          <%= render notifications %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <%= paginate @notifications %>
</div>
```

_notification.html.erb

```
<%= cache(['notifications', Notifications::VERSION, notification]) do %>
<div id="notification-<%= notification.id %>"
     data-id="<%= notification.id %>"
     class="media notification notification-<%= notification.notify_type %><%= ' unread' unless notification.read? %>">
  <div class="media-left">
    <% if notification.actor_profile_url && notification.actor_avatar_url %>
      <%= link_to image_tag(notification.actor_avatar_url), notification.actor_profile_url, title: notification.actor_name, class: 'user-avatar' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  <div class="media-body">
    <%= render partial: "/notifications/#{notification.notify_type}", locals: { notification: notification } %>
  </div>
  <div class="media-right">
    <%= l notification.created_at, format: :short %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

notification _follow.html.erb

```
<div class="media-heading">
  <%= link_to notification.actor.username, notification.actor %> just followed you.
</div>
```

routes.rb

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do

  mount Notifications::Engine => "/notifications"


  mount Payola::Engine => '/payola', as: :payola
  mount CountryStateSelect::Rails::Engine, at: "/"

  devise_for :admins
  devise_for :users

  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'user_auth'
    end
  end

  devise_scope :user do
    put 'user_change_plan', :to => 'users/registrations#user_change_plan'
    put 'user_update_credit_card', :to => 'users/registrations#user_update_credit_card'
    authenticated do
      root to: 'user_dashboard#index', as: 'authenticated_user_root'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'home#index', as: 'unauthenticated_user_root'
    end
  end
  end

  devise_scope :admin do
    authenticated do
      root to: 'admin_dashboard#admin', as: 'authenticated_admin_root'
    end

    unauthenticated do
      root to: 'home#index', as: 'unauthenticated_admin_root'
    end
  end


  controller :home do
    get :index, to: 'home#index', as: 'home', :path => 'home'
    get :login_portal, to: 'home#login_portal', as: 'login_portal', :path => 'login_portal'
    get :signup_portal, to: 'home#signup_portal', as: 'signup_portal', :path => 'signup_portal'
  end

  resources :user_dashboard, as: 'dashboard', :only => [:index, :show]
  resources :comments
  resources :posts do
    member do
      post :share
      put 'like', to: 'posts#like'
      get 'like', to: 'posts#like'
    end
  end

  resources :users, only: [:show, :index, :update], path: 'u' do
    get 'users/:username' => 'users#show'
    patch 'users/:username', to: 'users#update'
    resources :follows, :only => [:create, :destroy]
  end
  controller :favorites do
    get 'favorites/index'
  end

  resource :user_profile, :only => [:edit, :update], path: 'profile'
    root 'home#index'
end
```

I tried to include the Notifications module instead of wrapping the controller inside of it. It doesn't work as well.

```
500 Internal Server Error If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.
```

Comment: The error is undefined local variable or method `dashboard_index_path' but you have not shown your paths or routes or result of rake routes. The only route you show is to user_dashboard not dashboards

Answer (score 0):

Change your routes as following:

```
resource :user_dashboard, as: 'dashboard', only: :show
```

And your link looks like this

```
<%= active_link_to dashboard_path, class_active: 'nav-link active', :class_inactive => 'inactive' do %>
```

Comment: As you can see, the navigation bar is ok. For some reason, its checking for a class object and not the User **for #<#<Class:0xc0ceb08>:0xc0ccff0>):**

Comment: I emailed the author of the gem - Hopefully, he can give me more insight on his gem. This solution seems to be the most straight forward for notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `main_app` prefix on each link on the navbar e.g `main_app.dashboard_index_path`...

See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html#class-Rails::Engine-label-Using+Engine-27s+routes+outside+Engine) for more details.